# How to programmatically create Kafka broker instance?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is there any Java Kafka API available to **create Kafka server Instance**.

I searched Apache Kafka, but it doesn't have any method to create broker instance

Comment: Jenkins is written in Java... Jenkins can run Terraform or Ansible... Terraform and/or Ansible can create clusters...

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Servers (brokers) are expected to be independent jvms so you'd want to use some orchestration that can manage jvms.